# How do you manage secret keys and heroku with Ruby on Rails 4.1.0beta1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

With the release of the secrets.yml file, I removed my reliance on Figaro and moved all of my keys to secrets.yml and added that file to .gitignore.

But when I tried to push to Heroku, Heroku said they needed that file in my repo in order to deploy the website.  which makes sense, but I don't want my keys in git if I can avoid it.

With Figaro, I would run a rake task to deploy the keys to heroku as env variables and keep application.yml in the .gitignore. Obviously, I can't do that any more.  So how do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[see this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)  for heroku settings

if u want to run on local use like this

KEY=xyz OTHER_KEY=123 rails s

Answer (score 22):

Secrets isn't a full solution to the environment variables problem and it's not a direct replacement for something like [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).  Think of Secrets as an extra interface you're now supposed to use between your app and the broader world of environment variables.  That's why you're now supposed to call variables by using `Rails.application.secrets.your_variable` instead of `ENV["your_variable"]`.

The `secrets.yml` file itself is that interface and it's not meant to contain *actual* secrets (it's not well named).  You can see this because, even in the examples from the documentation, Secrets imports environment variables for any sensitive values (e.g. the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` value) and it's automatically checked into source control.

So rather than trying to hack Secrets into some sort of full-flow environment variable management solution, go with the flow:

1. Pull anything sensitive out of `secrets.yml`.
2. Check `secrets.yml` into source control like they default you to.
3. For all sensitive values, import them from normal environment variables into secrets ERB (e.g. `some_var: <%= ENV["some_var"] %>`)
4. Manage those ENV vars as you normally would, for instance using the Figaro gem.
5. Send the ENV vars up to Heroku as you normally would, for instance using the Figaro gem's rake task.

The point is, it doesn't matter how you manage your ENV vars -- whether it's manually, using Figaro, a `.env` file, whatever... `secrets.yml` is just an interface that translates these ENV vars into your Rails app.

Though it adds an extra step of abstraction and some additional work, there are advantages to using this interface approach.

Whether you believe it's conceptually a good idea or not to use Secrets, it'll save you a LOT of headache to just go with the flow on this one.

PS. If you do choose to hack it, be careful with the `heroku_secrets` gem.  As of this writing, it runs as a `before_initialize` in the startup sequence so your ENV vars will NOT be available to any config files in your `config/environments/` directory (which is where you commonly would put them for things like Amazon S3 keys).

Comment: I would like a way to have secrets just pointing sensitive keys for production and keep it for development, but even with no production keys, should be possible has working in different Heroku envs and not expose in a repo

Answer (score 7):

An equivalent for secrets.yml of that Figaro task is provided by the heroku_secrets gem, from https://github.com/alexpeattie/heroku_secrets:

```
gem 'heroku_secrets', github: 'alexpeattie/heroku_secrets'
```

This lets you run

```
rake heroku:secrets RAILS_ENV=production
```

to make the contents of secrets.yml available to heroku as environment variables.

Comment: if you make the contents of secrets.yml available to heroku, then do you keep them in the secrets.yml file also or no? Do you upload that secrets.yml to github? If you use that gem, does that gem handle hiding the secrets.yml file from being exposed to public on github?

Comment: You don't make secrets.yml available in your repository (heroku or github). Secrets.yml is added to your .gitignore file, which means it is not added to version control (git). Secretes.yml only 'lives' on your local machine/development environment.