# Rails & Heroku & Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

On localhost everything is ok but on heroku I'm getting some errors.

On Heroku :

[image]

and card input is missing:

[image]

And on localhost:

[image]

I believe is something with Api key but I don't understand what I did wrong:

```
config/initializers/stripe.rb :


Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_private_key
StripeEvent.signing_secret = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_webhook_secret

StripeEvent.configure do |config|
  config.subscribe "charge." do |event|
    Webhooks::Charge.new(event).call
  end
end

secrets.yml:

development:
stripe_private_key: 'sk_test_*********'
stripe_public_key: 'pk_test_**********'
stripe_webhook_secret: 'whsec_**********'
```

in production I'm using the same test keys because I didn't setup live keys

```
production:
stripe_private_key: 'sk_test_********'
stripe_public_key: 'pk_test_*********'
stripe_webhook_secret: 'whsec_*********'
```

if I'm pushing submit button on heroku :
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Update:

[image]

I have multiple because I tried so manny things.

Answer (score 0):

Your `secrets.yml` file is likely non-existant on your production server. It should be in your `.gitignore`, of course, but you need to make sure those secrets are available somehow on Heroku as well.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948799/100328) for some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: I made a update to my question. I believe I have the key in heroku.