# Rails app fails to compile on Heroku because of Devise secret_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I've tried all night to deploy to Heroku, but I keep getting the same error:

> remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset >pipeline
>   remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
>   remote:        rake aborted!
>   remote:        Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
>   remote:        config.secret_key = 'secret token string'
>   remote:        Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.

...

> remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
>   remote:  !
>   remote:
>   remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
>   remote:
>   remote: Verifying deploy...
>   remote:
>   remote: !       Push rejected to viral-blocitoff.
>   remote:
>   To https://git.heroku.com/viral-blocitoff.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/viral-blocitoff.git'

I also ran the following to set my environment variable for heroku:

```
    figaro heroku:set -e production
```

This read all my fixed values, including SENDGRID and DEVISE_SECRET_KEY

Here is my application.yml file (minus the fixed values):

```
    SENDGRID_PASSWORD: ********
    SENDGRID_USERNAME: @heroku.com

    production:
      SECRET_KEY_BASE: secret token
      DEVISE_SECRET_KEY: secret token
```

This is what I have in my devise.rb file:

```
    config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']
```

I looked at other proposed solutions on this site, but I made Devise work on another app less than two months ago without going through such tasks. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080910/devise-secret-key-was-not-set#answer-22584303

Comment: you must have added `application.yml` in `.gitignore` so, make sure you have set the environment variables either manually via GUI inside `settings` or using `Figaro` and you have no alignment issues in YAML

Comment: The app works in development when running on Rails server--no hang ups at all, with authentication, emails, or other things.

Comment: @CbaBhusal I did use figaro to set my environment variables, and I confirmed with the command "heroku config"  The variables showed the same fixed values I have in application.yml.  I'm trying to think of what sort of alignment issues there could be?

Comment: @CbaBhusal yes, I do have application.yml in .gitignore.  however I pushed secrets.yml to my remote on github, but it does not have the actual values.

Comment: try once running you app in production mode in local `rails s -e production`

Comment: @CbaBhusal tried to run it in production locally, got the welcome page, but could not sign in.  Error message: something went wrong, check logs.  But was able to run app in development locally, with no functionality problems.  scratching my head?

Comment: ok then try pre-compiling the assets in local and push

Answer (score 0):

Got it to deploy.  I unset my heroku env variables, then reset them.  I also used one token (via ENV variable) for both development and production secret_key_base  Pushed remote master to Heroku, it compiled and launched.  Then migrated the database too to Heroku.  All is well.

Answer (score 0):

My application was reporting the same error, however, the issue results from a combination of using the **Figaro** gem and rigid systemAdmin.  Upon implementing the **Figaro** gem, creating a *secrets.yml* file for assigning authentication tokens, then appropriately storing it within *.gitignore*, a conflict can occur when attempting to deploy to heroku because the *.gitignore* prevents pushing the *secrets.yml* file credentials necessary for deployment.

Specifically, I used the following gem and procedure to resolve the conflict.

1. `gem 'heroku_secrets', github: 'alexpeattie/heroku_secrets'`
2. `bundle install`
3. `git push heroku master --force`

The abovementioned solution is explained further in a related StackOverflow post: [How do you manage secret keys and heroku with Ruby on Rails 4.1.0beta1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544626/how-do-you-manage-secret-keys-and-heroku-with-ruby-on-rails-4-1-0beta1/22458102#22458102)

Moreover, I've encountered multiple issues using **Figaro** in ***Rails 4.1***; I've detailed problems associated with administration of *secrets.yml* at the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/766048b8d13f76ccdb80).

Hopefully this helps-thanks!