# using figaro to store env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm confused about how to properly use figaro with Rails 4.2. So in application.yml (which is checked into .gitignore), I have this:

`secret_key_base: 123456`

And then in secrets.yml, I have this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

The gem should be handling the ENV part of setting the credentials, according to everything I've read. Why is this not working?

EDIT 1: 
In application.yml I have: `mandrill_user_name: email@example.com` and `mandrill_password: 1234567890`

And in development.rb I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "localhost:3000",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["mandrill_user_name"],
  password: ENV["mandrill_password"]
}
```

Shouldn't application.yml be taking care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is redundant to have the variable in the secrets.yml file and the application.yml file.
**I.e. use the application.yml file ONLY to declare ENV Vars.**

So long as it is in the apllication.yml file you can call it throughout your rails app just like you are doing:

```
ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

Varialbles stored in the secrets.yml file are called via

```
Rails.application.secrets.SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm severely confused. It doesn't work, so I think I'm doing something wrong. I have `secret_key_base: 123456` in application.yml, and then I call it in development.rb with `ENV["secret_key_base"]`. Nothing happens. Also, if it's redundant to use secrets.yml, why does this answer say otherwise?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569119/2009652

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens?

Comment: I have `mandrill_password: 1234567890` set in application.yml and `password: ENV["mandrill_password"]` set in the action mailer config in development.rb. The expected action is that a user can put their email into a form I've created, and hit submit to sign up. This then sends them an email. Everything is set up, and I'm successful at getting this to work just fine until I try storing the mandrill credentials in ENV variables. So when I say "nothing happens" in this case I mean I get no email. In other cases - like storing the application key in an ENV variable - it causes $rails s to not load

Comment: can you add your development.rb action mailer config code to your post

Comment: also run the following commands in terminal: "spring stop" then "spring start"

Comment: 1) is figaro in your Gemfile? 2) did you restart spring? 3) did you restart your webserver after updating your application.yml file? –

Comment: I'm certain that I had the first two done, but probably forgot to restart the webserver. I'm not entirely certain how, but it works now. What does spring do?

Comment: Also, what's the point of secrets.yml if figaro does it better?

Comment: And is it safe to keep development and test env secrets in the repository?

Comment: 1) spring auto loads the environment so you can perform tasks faster (bin/rake, bin/rails). 2) the file becomes relatively worthless, just leave it there the way it is generated when you create the project or you will run into error when committing to heroku 3) it's best practice not to store them in the repo 4) if this solved your problems mark the answer correct